# How to create elements HTML in JS and align name on the top of the message box from a chat

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a chat, and I have a problem, I want the user's name to be on top of the message box, just as it is in Messenger, but I can't, I've tried some ways and it didn't work, I don't have a wide knowledge about CSS, so it becomes difficult for me
Which property should I use to align the name right above the message box? Margin, position? What should I do, I have no idea to solve this

Also, I want to know how to create these elements by using JS, you know, I'm using PHP and JS, so I want to use JS to create the message every time a user click in a button, it is a public chat and will have lot of users

**My JS:**

```
    var conn = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");



    conn.onmessage = function(e){
        SendMessage('him', e.data); //It is using the him class

    };

    conn.onclose = function(e){
        console.log("Connection is closed!");
    }

    var content = document.getElementById('chat');
    var name = '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>';
    var message = document.getElementById('message'); //It takes the user message
    var button = document.getElementById('send');

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){

            

        var msg = {
            name: name,
            message: message.value
        };
                
        msg = JSON.stringify(msg);

        conn.send(msg);
        SendMessage('me', msg); //It uses the me class
        message.value = '';
    });

    function SendMessage(who, data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', who); //It means, who is sending? Me or him?


        var span = document.createElement('span'); //It is used to the message
        span.textContent = data.message;

        
        div.appendChild(span);

        content.appendChild(div); //Then the div class will append everything
    }
```

**A simple image from Messenger chat:**

[image of example with name of the user on the top of the message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaBzu.jpg)

**My code snippnet, I want something like this, but with the name on the top, as the image from messenger:**

```css
      ul li{
                display:inline-block;
                clear: both;
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 2px;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            
            }

            .him{
                background: yellow;
                float: left;
            }

            .me{
                float: right;
                background: #0084ff;
                color: #fff;
            }

            .him + .me{
                border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            }

            .me + .me{
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
            }

            .me:last-of-type {
                border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
            }

            .him .user {
                font-size:0.6em;
                color: grey;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
            }
                
            .me .user {
                font-size:0.6em;
                color: grey;
                margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
                <li class="him">
                    <div class="user">Username</div>
                    <div class="msg">
                        <span>Hello World</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="me">
                    <div class="user">Username</div>
                    <div class="msg">
                        <span>Hello World</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="him">
                    <div class="user">Username</div>
                    <div class="msg">
                        <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                

            </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want the name outside of the bubble, but grouped with it?

Comment: Yes, I want it, you're right

Comment: You need [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position): https://jsfiddle.net/q583xpfo/ (and `relative` for the parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can simply achieve this with [`position: absolute;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Then to make its position relative to its parent you need to assign [`position: relative;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) to its parent also.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.him, .me {
  position: relative;
}

.him {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.me {
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.him+.me {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me+.me {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.him .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.me .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.user {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="me">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
      </div>
    </li>


  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

### Update

As @ChrisG mentioned in comments to remove the next same sibling username you can simply do it with [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) like this:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.him,
.me {
  position: relative;
}

.him {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.me {
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.him+.me {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me+.me {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.him .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.me .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.user {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
}

.him+.him .user,
.me+.me .user {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="me">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="me">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>Hello World</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="him">
      <div class="user">Username</div>
      <div class="msg">
        <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
      </div>
    </li>


  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Since your template for both sides is like the same you simply create a string template then replace the data inside it then you can append it to your HTML with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) like this:

```js
var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
var send = document.getElementById('send');

function SendMessage(who, data) {

  var html = '<li class="' + who + '">' +
    '<div class="user">Username</div>' +
    '<div class="msg">' +
    '<span>' + data.message + '</span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</li>';

  chat.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

send.addEventListener('click', function() {
  SendMessage('him', {
    message: 'hi'
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.him,
.me {
  position: relative;
}

.him {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.me {
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.him+.me {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me+.me {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.him .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.me .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.user {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
}

.him+.him .user,
.me+.me .user {
  display: none;
}

#send {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="chat"></ul>
  <button id="send">Send</button>
</body>

</html>
```

While there is no major advantage for using create elements in these days and working with string in easier and simpler in this particular case I encourage to use the first approach instead but as you request this approach also I will add it, and it should be like this:

```js
var chat = document.getElementById('chat');
var send = document.getElementById('send');

function SendMessage(who, data) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add(who);
  var userName = document.createElement('div');
  userName.classList.add('user');
  userName.textContent = 'Username';
  li.appendChild(userName);
  var msg = document.createElement('div');
  msg.classList.add('msg');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = data.message;
  msg.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(msg);

  chat.appendChild(li);
}

send.addEventListener('click', function() {
  SendMessage('him', {
    message: 'hi'
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.him,
.me {
  position: relative;
}

.him {
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.me {
  float: right;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
}

.him+.me {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me+.me {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.me:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.him .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.me .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.user {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
}

.him+.him .user,
.me+.me .user {
  display: none;
}

#send {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="chat"></ul>
  <button id="send">Send</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** I just hardcode the message and the owner of it for more illustration, you should replace them with actual data.

Comment: Good, what if the user send more than one message, how to hide the name?

Comment: This should do it: `.him + .him .user { display: none; }`

Comment: Hello @SMAKSS. Can you help me?

Comment: @AnneRebb How can I help you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179596/how-to-align-username-outside-the-bubble-in-chat

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to align items more effectivly.

Only the message portion should be filled in with color; not the entire list item.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none
}

ul li {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
}

.him { align-self: flex-start; }
.me  { align-self: flex-end; }

.msg {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.him .user { text-align: left;  margin-left: 10px; }
.me  .user { text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; }

.him .msg { background: yellow; }
.me  .msg { background: #0084ff; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="him">
    <div class="user">Bob</div>
    <div class="msg">
      <span>Hello World</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="me">
    <div class="user">Me</div>
    <div class="msg">
      <span>Hello World</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="him">
    <div class="user">Bob</div>
    <div class="msg">
      <span>How to put the name on the top</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's great, that's what I want, could you help me with the JS?

Comment: Please help me with JavaScript

Comment: @AnneRebb I am sorry, but if you do not understand JavaScript, please take a look at the documentation. Just search for "MDN" in google. If you need a tutorial on JavaScript principles, try [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/)